# React native IOS InputAccessoryView disappear from the screen after close modal

Tags: ios, react-native, inputaccessoryview

When I have on my screen InputAccessoryView which has component without nativeID (So it is constantly showing even if the keyboard is not shown) and I open and close Modal (react-native modal) then InputAccessoryView disappear from the screen with the component. I don't know why this is happening and also I don't know how to keep this InputAccessoryView on the screen.

Here is the code to reproduce it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, AppRegistry, TextInput, InputAccessoryView, Button } from 'react-native';
import {Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, Alert} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: 'Placeholder Text', modalVisible: false,};
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22, padding: 50, backgroundColor: '#0066ff'}}>
            <View>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text style={{color:"#ffffff"}}>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>


        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#6ED4C8'}}>
         <Text></Text>
          <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text style={{padding: 40, backgroundColor: "#ff3300"}}>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </ScrollView>
        <InputAccessoryView backgroundColor="#ff9900" >
           <TextInput
            style={{
              padding: 20,
              paddingTop: 50,
            }}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
        </InputAccessoryView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here you can find the online version (Keep in mind that the issue is only relevant for IOS): 
https://snack.expo.io/SJB7ipm6B

Some Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your time and your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this. I am re-rendering `InputAccessoryView` once the modal is closed

```
{(!this.state.modalVisible) && <InputAccessoryView backgroundColor="#ff9900">
           <TextInput
            style={{
              padding: 20,
              paddingTop: 50,
            }}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
        </InputAccessoryView>}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Yes this is working although I am interested also why is happening.

Comment: i think the render method recalculates because of the state change on modalvisible, since it does that, it re-renders the inputaccesoryview;

Comment: yes unfortunately this is needed and works, however it's less smooth and ideal then the render you see on whatsapp when sliding back

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same issue. After digging around for a while I figured out that setting the [presentationStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#presentationstyle) prop to `overFullScreen` on the modal fixes it for me without re-rendering the InputAccessoryView.